Can't get matplotlib figures to show in WSL ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I did the following in order, trying to show a dummy plot in python each time (and getting a different error):
python -m pip install PyQt5
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM='xcb'
sudo apt install libxcb-xinerama0 libqt5x11extras5
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

The last error is:
>>> plt.show()
WARNING: dzn is not a conformant Vulkan implementation, testing use only.
WARNING: Some incorrect rendering might occur because the selected Vulkan device (Microsoft Direct3D12 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070)) doesn't support base Zink requirements: feats.features.logicOp have_EXT_custom_border_color have_EXT_line_rasterization

and the plot window appears black and is not interactive. I understand I can disable the GPU use but my CPU does not have integrated graphics. Does this mean I have to install CUDA drivers in WSL or something? Is there a way to get this to work or should I just plot my stuff through powershell/jupyter notebook?
